# Not possible to move mask? Unable to get bbox of mask element

Tags: javascript, svg, svg.js

I've exported an SVG image from Sketch and wanted to animate it via svg.js. When trying to move parts of the image, svg.js throws an error:

```
Getting bbox of element "mask" is not possible.
```

See screenshot below.

[image]

Anything wrong with the SVG markup? Or does svg.js need additional input for moving masks?

[image]

Comment: you need to get the bbox of the path or paths inside the mask - in this case the use element `#path-12`

Comment: And please decide to ask a question here or on github but not both!